# Accessing one namespace's variable in another (JS Module pattern)

Tags: javascript

Say I have some namespace which contains a variable

```
const Game = (function() {
    let direction = "right";
})();
```

And I need access to that variable in a different module

```
(function() {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case 65:
            direction...
    }
})();
```

What is the syntax for accessing that variable in place of "direction..."?

1) What if I want direction to be directly returned by the return {} block in Game? For example: return { direction: direction }

2) What if I want direction to be a part of a function that is returned by the return {} block in Game? For example: return { init: init } where init is a function which contains the variable I want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
const Game = (function() {
    let direction = "right";

    function getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    function setDirection(dir) {
        direction = dir;
    }

    return {
        getDirection,
        setDirection,
    };
})();
```

And in your other module:

```
(function() {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case 65:
            Game.setDirection('left');
    }
})();
```